# Regression with percentage-point change as dependent variable

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, percentage

I want to look at the correlation between a change in prevalence of a particular outcome (expressed in percentage points) and a continuous predictor variable which is an index. So for the response variable, I have a range of values between -1 and 1, while for the predictor, the range is between 0 and 1.

While a linear model does give a significant result, it doesn't make sense for the data as it will give predictions outside outside the possible range. A beta regression requires that all observations be between 0 and 1, so it doesn't allow for a negative change. Is there an appropriate transformation or glm that should be used for this kind of data?

Comment: Have you considered using the post-intervention value as the outcome variable and incorporating the pre-intervention value in some way as a predictor? Percentage changes can be very poorly behaved as response variables.

Comment: Why would it be bound by -1 & 1? Certainly things can increase by 200%, eg. Can you say more about what your variables actually are?

Comment: Another classic is for $R \in (-100\%, \infty]$ compute $r = \log(1 +R)$.